# Potential ways to push notifications from a server service to a winforms client application in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I'm currently developing a winforms client application in C# (.NET 4). Part of the application includes a task notification system.  On the SQL server end, I have a service which runs to calculate which scheduled events are current and create tasks for relevant users and groups.

My question is, what would be the most efficient way to grab those tasks from the server.  We will have about 30 users and initially I had thought they could all poll the server once a minute to see if they have new tasks, but then remembered that you can have clients subscribe to notifications (certainly through web services) and wondered if this can be achieved with a server service too?

What would be the recommended approach, given the current architecture?  Can a winform client subscribe to notifications from a server service?

Comment: You can use WCF duplex for that. And yes wcf services can run as a service.

Comment: here is a good link and tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service

Comment: Okay thanks, I briefly looked at WCF a while back but that was with a web based project.  I'll look into it again.  Would this be a better approach / more efficient than polling?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Will your application only run on microsoft platforms or not?

Comment: If you go a web oriented approach, you should check out [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) as an alternative to WCF.